# Packing a 3rd party framework into my own library/framework on iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, static-libraries, ios-frameworks

I'm trying to build an SDK for other developers to use. On this SDK I'm using other 3rd parties frameworks.
I can deliver the SDK with the 3rd party Frameworks but I want the integration would be as simple as possible so it would be really nice if I could pack it all into one framework file.

I've succeeded to pack the device and simulator .a file using aggregate and lipo, But I can't find how to add 3rd party frameworks to this package.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used this code:
https://github.com/kstenerud/iOS-Universal-Framework

Using "Fake Framework" solved all my problems!